# loop through files in document set using javascript

Tags: javascript, document-set

is there a way to loop through the files in a document set using Javascript? I am not able to find a way to access those files. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to use JavaScript go thru the files into a shared document library ? You could use my JavaScript API to do it...
So with jQuery and [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/) it will look like that:

```
$SP().list("My Shared Documents").get({
  // "BaseName" is the name of the file/folder;
  // "FileRef" is the full path of the file/folder;
  // "FSObjType" is 0 for a file and 1 for a folder (you need to apply $SP().cleanResult())
  fields:"BaseName,FileRef,FSObjType", 
  folderOptions:{
    path:"My Folder/Sub Folder/",
    show:"FilesAndFolders_Recursive" /* several options for that one -- see the documentation */
  }
}, function(files) {
  for (var i=0; i<files.length; i++) console.log(files[i].getAttribute("FileRef"))
});
```

Comment: No, the OP is asking how to iterate the files in a "Document Set", not the "Shared Documents" document library.

Answer (score 0):

There is a specific set of CSOM commands for document sets. There's a [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mittals/archive/2013/04/03/how-to-create-a-document-set-in-sharepoint-2013-using-javascript-client-side-object-model-jsom.aspx) on MSDN that covers creating a document set with JavaScript. It won't specifically address your question of iterating through the files in a document set, but it should point you in the right direction, to the right libraries, where you can extract the methods.